# SharePoint Workflow Error: "Unable to transform the input lookup data into the requested type" BUT only on New Item Creation

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, lookup, sharepoint-workflow

FYI to start, I am aware of how to properly set up an update to a lookup, and am 99% positive I've done this correctly.

I know this because When I set the workflow to automatically start when an Item is Changed, then it works perfectly.  But when I simply change this setting so it will automatically start on New Item Creation, it Cancels the workflow and I get a "Coercion Failed: Unable to transform the input lookup data into the requested type." If both options are checked then it fails on creation, but simply clicking edit on the item properties, and the "Save" makes it work.

The workflow is on a Document Library and works as follows;

User selects the Work Task LookUp from a dropdown in the edit properties form after uploading, and then Saves the item (adding it to the document library).  The workflow is suppose to then look at the Work Task LookUp selected, and pull the Account and Effective Date-Type lookUp ID's that Work Task item has, and sets the Document's identical fields to the same value.

Here is the code for the workflow if it helps;

```
If Current Item: Parent Task is not empty
If Current Item: Sub Task is not empty
    Log Both are empty to workflow history list
    Then Set Account to Work Tasks:Account
    The Log Set Account to workflow history list
    Then Set Effective Date and Type to WorkTasks: Effective Date and Type
    The Log Set EffDateType to the workflow history list
```

This is all done in one step.  I also added additional steps to test if the account and effective date type fields have been set properly, and if not to set them again.  But everytime I run the workflow on change and it works, it always correctly sets these fields based upon the first Step (posted above) and the additional check logs to the history that they are not needed.

As an example, The lookUp for Integer for Tasks:Account is set to work as follows;

```
Date Source: Work Tasks (a list)
Field from Source: Account (a lookup)
Return Field as: Lookup ID (as Integer)

Find the List Item
Field: Title (from the Work Tasks list)
Value: Current Item: Parent Task (Which is a look up of the "Title" 
Field from Work Tasks List, and is set to return the Value as a LookUp Value (As Text))
```

The Effective Date and Type setting is pretty much identical.

So anyone have any insight?  I've tried running it as an impersonated Step, setting a workflow pause (for 1 minute), changing the lookup types incase I messed it up to start with, but ultimately the above workflow DOES work, but only when I set it to "**Automatically start on the Change (edit) of an Item**", NOT "**Automatically start on New Item Creation**" like I need to to do.

Oh yes, fyi, I am using SPServices CascadingDropDown on the Work Task and Sub Task fields of the doc Library form, but I honestly do not believe this has anything to do with my issue.

**UPDATE:**

I've talked with another developer, and he believes it is due to the issue that the workflow is occuring too quickly, before the item creates an ID for itself, which it needs to conduct the lookUps.  He had me add another "Pause Workflow" to the very top of my workflow code (above the If conditions) and set it for 1 minute.

It then worked properly.

Downside is we want this to labeling to occur as close to item creation as possible.  Because a view of the library relies on grouping based upon Account and Effective Date and Type.  To add to this downer, Microsoft's Pause Workflow only allows for 1 minute or more, and then the timer used for this is often off, resulting in a pause longer than that.  So far, every test is currently showing 2 minutes minimum on the pause.

A possible alternative solution for instantaniously populate the fileds is to use Javascript and SPServices to do the lookUp to the Task list to pull the account and effective date - type fields and then populate, but my Javascript is not very strong and I would need help doing this.  If anyone has any suggestions, I would appreciate them.

Comment: In my case the workflow caused this error when I try to set a variable with a value from a lookup field that was not set. To solve the issue I had to check first the if lookup is empty.

Answer (score 1):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I don't know if it is the ID for the item after further testing. I changed the start of the workflow to wait until a field in the item changes. I set it to wait until the ID field is not 0 (since you cannot set to null), and it still does not work.

```
 6/14/2012 4:13 PM Comment System Account Waiting on ID ​ 
 6/14/2012 4:13 PM Comment System Account Waiting complete on ID ​ 
 6/14/2012 4:13 PM Error System Account Coercion Failed: Unable to transform the input lookup data into the requested type.
```

> I have tried other fields as well, like document ID value is not empty, and it will wait, log it finishing the wait, and then fail.
>
> **UPDATE** This issue has something to do with the Parent Task field. I have solved the issue without having to wait for a period of time by setting the change from above to wait until the Parent Task field is not empty. It then completes the workflow fine.
>
> Anyone know why there is a delay though? I've solved it, but still don't fully understand what takes it so long.

The main fault has been solved (hence the answer), and the remaining point about the reasons for the delay would probably be a discussion point or not specific enough for SO. Any further clarification can be edited in here.